# button change jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to change my button to "remove" if i clicked the "add to stay button"
Like when i click the add button it will load the data then it will be changed to remove button because it is already added.
and if i press the remove button how can it go back to "add to your stay" button? Here is my js code and My button code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addons").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('addon-id');
    console.log(id);

    if (id != '') {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Pages/addonajax",
        data: {
          id: id
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.dir(data);
          if (data) {
            result = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#test4>span").html(result[0]['name']);
            $("#test5>span").html(result[0]['price']);
            $("#test2>span").append(result[0]['price']);
          } else {
            $('#test1').append('no records found');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="bookingroom">Total: PHP 2,750.00</h3>
<h5 class="addon-taxes2">Including Taxes & Fees</h5>
<button class="addons addon-btn trans_200">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
```

here's the example fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/j501fwb8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much harder to maintain a single element that has to do multiple things based on some criteria.  Instead I highly suggest using multiple elements with a [Single Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

I'd also HIGHLY recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript - Philip Walton (Engineer @ Google)](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/)

My example would be something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-btn-addon').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    /// do whatever
    var addonId = $this.data('addon-id');
    $this.addClass('is-hidden');
    $('.js-btn-remove[data-addon-id="' + addonId + '"]').removeClass('is-hidden');
  });
  $('.js-btn-remove').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    /// do whatever
    var addonId = $this.data('addon-id');
    $this.addClass('is-hidden');
    $('.js-btn-addon[data-addon-id="' + addonId + '"]').removeClass('is-hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="addons addon-btn js-btn-addon trans_200" data-addon-id = "1">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
<button class="addons addon-btn js-btn-remove is-hidden trans_200" data-addon-id = "1">Remove</button>
<br/>

<button class="addons addon-btn js-btn-addon trans_200" data-addon-id = "2">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
<button class="addons addon-btn js-btn-remove is-hidden trans_200" data-addon-id = "2">Remove</button>
<br/>

<button class="addons addon-btn js-btn-addon trans_200" data-addon-id = "3">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
<button class="addons addon-btn js-btn-remove is-hidden trans_200" data-addon-id = "3">Remove</button>
<br/>
```

Comment: Great answer to the question the OP probably wishes they had asked. Thanks for the supplemental reading materials.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the HTML of the element to say Remove by using:

```
$(".addons").html('Remove');
```

You will have to handle the onClick method functionality accordingly though. Or you can remove the button altogether and show a different one.

Answer (score 1):

You can change text after ajax call and load data, also you can add class for remove process etc.

Note: here i remove your ajax call, just put `.text()` on ajax success when load data

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".addons").on("click", function(event) {
 
    var _t = $(this);
    if(_t.hasClass('remove')){
      _t.removeClass('remove').text('ADD TO MY STAY');
    } else {
      _t.addClass('remove').text('Remove');
    }

  

});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class = "bookingroom">Total: PHP 2,750.00</h3>
      <h5 class = "addon-taxes2">Including Taxes & Fees</h5>
      <button class="addons addon-btn trans_200">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
```

Comment: if i press the remove button how can it go back to "add to your stay" button? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class to mark the button once it has been used to add the item. Wrapping the execution code inside an if/else block lets you check whether the class exists so you can act accordingly.

See the comments in this suggested code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".addons").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('addon-id');
    console.log(id);
      if (id != ''){

        // Tests which type of button this is (see below)
        if(!this.classList.contains("isRemoveButton")){
      
          /* Your ajax call for adding goes here */

          // Changes the button text
          $(this).text("REMOVE");

          // Adds a class indicating which type of button this is
          this.classList.add("isRemoveButton");

        } else {

          /* Different ajax call for removing goes here */

          // Restores original button text
          $(this).text("ADD TO MY STAY");

          // Restores original classList state
          this.classList.remove("isRemoveButton");
        }
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 class="bookingroom">Total: PHP 2,750.00</h3>
<h5 class="addon-taxes2">Including Taxes & Fees</h5>
<button class="addons addon-btn trans_200" data-addon-id="1">ADD TO MY STAY</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".addons").on("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var id = $(this).data('addon-id');
   console.log(id);

  if(id != '')

    {
        $.ajax(
      {
        type:"POST",
        url : "Pages/addonajax",
        data:{id:id},


        success:function(data)
        {
          console.dir(data);
          if (data) {


          result = JSON.parse(data);

          $("#test4>span").html(result[0]['name']);
          $("#test5>span").html(result[0]['price']);
          $("#test2>span").append(result[0]['price']);
          }
          else {
             $('#test1').append('no records found');
          }


        }
      });
    }

  $(this).hide();
  $('.remove').show();
  //and write a remove property which you want.
 });

 $('.remove').on("click", function(){
  //write your property here for remove once.
  $(".addons").show();
  $(this).hide();
 })

});
```

Comment: Code only answers are usually not helpful.  Please add some commentary to point out what the issue was, and what you did to fix it.

Comment: Sure thank you i will try from next time. Really appreciated.

Comment: and if i press the remove button how can it go back to "add to your stay" button?

Comment: Then onclick of remove again show the addons button. its upon you how to show your buttton.

Comment: im sorry i cant fully understand can you please give an example?

Comment: Sure give me some time 2 . min.

Comment: Check the above code now i have edited how you wanted.

Comment: oh ok i got the idea thanks btw do you have idea that will alert like "Do you really wish to delete this item? Yes or no" something like that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203447/discussion-between-jed-jamir-and-chandankr).